# Faster way to get substring in python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, algorithm, performance

I am coding Skew Algorithm to construct the Suffix Array and I have a long string (length >= 4000).
In Skew Algorithm, I have to construct the **Triples Array** and **Sub-strings Array**.

For example : I have a string `s = 'abcddd'`.

- **Triples Array** is : `'abc', 'bcd', 'cdd', 'ddd'`
- **Sub-strings Array** is : `'abcddd', 'bcddd', 'cddd', 'ddd', 'dd', 'd'`

This is my solution :

```
import numpy as np

# example
string = 'abdcb.....' (length >= 4000)
temp = 'abdcb......###' (length >= 4000)

triples_arr = np.array([])
sub_strings = np.array([])

for i in range (0, len(temp) - 3):
    triples_arr = np.append(triples_arr, temp[i:i + 3])
    sub_strings = np.append(sub_strings, string[i:string_len])
```

With a long string (length >= 4000), it take a minute to complete.

Is there any solution that I can decrease the processing time of that task?

Comment: I think when constructing a suffix array, you don't copy all the suffix, instead you use something more lightweight like starting position to represent a suffix

Comment: In Skew Algorithm, I need the triple suffix to sort and label with a character in the alphabet. The solution of @StephenRauch was solved my problem.

Comment: I think building the Triples Array is fine. But building the sub_strings array need n^2 space and time which defeats the purpose of building suffix array in linear time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using comprehensions, you can construct these strings faster than using a `for` loop:

#### Code:

```
triples_arr = [a_string[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a_string)-1)]
sub_strings = [a_string[i:] for i in range(len(a_string))]
```

#### Test Code:

```
a_string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

triples_arr = [a_string[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a_string)-2)]
print(triples_arr)

sub_strings = [a_string[i:] for i in range(len(a_string))]
print(sub_strings)
```

#### Results:

```
['abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def', 'efg', 'fgh', 'ghi', 'hij', 'ijk', 'jkl',
 'klm', 'lmn', 'mno', 'nop', 'opq', 'pqr', 'qrs', 'rst', 'stu', 'tuv',
 'uvw', 'vwx', 'wxy', 'xyz']
['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
 'cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
 'efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
 'ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
 'jklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'klmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'lmnopqrstuvwxyz',
 'mnopqrstuvwxyz', 'nopqrstuvwxyz', 'opqrstuvwxyz', 'pqrstuvwxyz',
 'qrstuvwxyz', 'rstuvwxyz', 'stuvwxyz', 'tuvwxyz', 'uvwxyz',
 'vwxyz', 'wxyz', 'xyz', 'yz', 'z']
```

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not work for you, but if you operate on `bytes` and `memoryview` objects instead of string objects, many optimizations become available. For example, it is very cheap to slice memoryviews.

Answer (score 0):

What about without any external lib and without any loop ?

```
Triples_Array=[]
Sub_strings=[]

def hello(data):
    if not data:
        return 0
    triple=data[:3]
    Sub_strings.append(data)
    if len(triple)==3:
        Triples_Array.append(triple)



    return hello(data[1:])
print(hello('abcddd'))

print(Sub_strings)
print(Triples_Array)
```

output:

```
['abcddd', 'bcddd', 'cddd', 'ddd', 'dd', 'd']
['abc', 'bcd', 'cdd', 'ddd']
```